# Ruby - Cant Access Parameter in Controller (or Model)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm very new to Ruby (this week) and was assigned an app to modify. I added a checkbox and am just trying to get the checkbox value on the server so I can do something. I've found quite a few examples of this on this site but nothing seems to work for me. I feel like I'm just doing what everyone else is doing!

```
  //View
  .field-row
    %label ID Check?
    = f.check_box :idvalue

 //Controller
 logger.info "DisplayParams: #{params}"
 logger.info "DisplayID: #{params[:idvalue]}"
 logger.info "DisplayID Another Way: #{:idvalue}"

 //Model
 logger.info "MODEL-ID: #{:idvalue}"
```

development.log after I click the checkbox and submit

```
[43de5....] MODEL-ID: idvalue
[43de5....] DisplayParams: "deleted_images"=>"","utf8"=>"/","year"=>"2018","country"=>"US","idvalue"=>"1"}
[43de5....] DisplayID:
[43de5....] DisplayID Another Way: idvalue
```

As you can see... the idvalue shows up when I print out the params but not when I try to display the actual id value. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong when trying to get this value?

I found a params.require section and added my variable there

If anyone has any thoughts I'd love to hear them. Once I can see this value in the Controller I eventually need to move it over to the Model.

thanks!

Comment: What do you get if you log `params.class`? Does it make a difference if you ask for `params["idvalue"]`? (It shouldn't, unless something is converting your params to a Hash before you get them.) Incidentally, `"#{:idvalue}"` is always going to return "idvalue", as you are just converting the symbol `:idvalue` to a string.

Comment: When I log params.class I get "ActionController::Parameters". When I tried params["idvalue"] it appears to just blow up. My screen goes blank on submit and a lot of weird stuff in the logs.  Thanks for the info on #{:idvalue}!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is wasn't as straightforward as I would have thought. 
Here is how it finally worked:

```
  def create
     @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params.merge(created_by_id: current_user.id))
     logger.info "SHOW ID: #{params[:vehicle][:idvalue]}"
```

Looks like I had to nest it within @vehicle!

thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be some issue with the params object itself, namely that there's an erroneous comma between year and the `=>`, aka the `"year",=>"2018"` should be `"year"=>"2018"`. Maybe that could give you something to look into? Another thing would be to try calling the string version of the param name rather than the symbol, `params['idvalue']`. Good luck! :D

```
params = {"deleted_images"=> "", "utf8"=> "/", "year"=> "2018", "country"=> "US", "idvalue"=> "1"}
params['idvalue']
#returns "1"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Oops.. that was my typo since I couldn't copy/paste from the server log. When I try params['idvalue'] I just get a null response.   [43de5....] DisplayID: